# storing date using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, date

is this mysql query right ? note that  the userbdate is Date

```
      sprintf("INSERT INTO userinfo (username,userbdate,national,email, mobilenum,phonenum,
                        street,city,stateof , postoofice,country,lastcirt,cirt,specailzation,exper,
                        yearsofexper,notes)
                        VALUES ('%s', '%d' , '%s' , '%s' , '%d' , '%d' ,
                        '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',
                        '%d','%s')",
                        $user->getUserName(),
                        $user->getgetBirthDate(),
                        $user->getNational(),
                        $user->getEmail(),
                        $user->getMobilenum(),
                        $user->getPhonenum(),
                        $user->getPhonenum(),
                        $user->getStreet(),
                        $user->getCity(),
                        $user->getStateof(),
                        $user->getPostoffice(),
                        $user->getCountry(),
                        $user->getLastcirifacite(),
                        $user->getCirifacite(),
                        $user->getSpecailaztion(),
                        $user->getExper(),
                        $user->getYearsOfexper(),
                        $user->Notes(),
                        $userModel->getUserId());
```

Comment: `postoofice` not sure if this is intentional or a typo

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it and see? We can't guess what all of your values are. But I can tell you right now that if **ANY** of those values have quotes in them, your SQL query is going to be broken. Look up SQL injection, visit http://bobby-tables.com, and make your query a little less risky.

Comment: mm , it's a final project for a subject , i'll try to read about it in this summer , but now i've to finish it 
BTW , I try but it give me nothing !

Comment: Then take the generated query and run it manually in the mysql monitor. Undoubtedly you'll get error messages. `specailzation` looks suspect.

Answer (score 0):

`getgetBirthDate` would seem wrong (two get's).
You would better use parameters and be done with any formatting issue. As an aside you would be immune to SQL injection.